# Multiple applications in same codeigniter installation sharing same view layout menu

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using a single codeigniter installation to host 2 applications.
But my problem is to share the same menu at the top of the page for both application.
With my actual files structure, I don't know how to have the same header or menu for both application.
Here is my actual structure :

```
system
application
--base_loisirs (folder application of base loisirs)
base_loisir.php (with $application_folder = 'application/base_loisirs';)
--parc_auto (folder application of parc auto)
parc_auto.php (with $application_folder = 'application/parc_auto';)
```

The folder application contain all the folders of different folders application.
Is it possible for me in the base loisir view for example, to include a layout included in the par auto folder or vice versa ? How ?

Comment: both application share data same or they have separate data also

Comment: have you tried require(),Include() function like require($_SERVER[‘DOCUMENT_ROOT’].’menu.php’)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create one **menu.php** on root folder

Now create one directory name '**common**' in view folder in both applications

```
/application
 /view
  /common ( new directory )
```

Now create another menu.php in common directory and put following code

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/menu.php');
```

Now load menu in any file of view using following code

```
<?php echo $this->load->view('common/menu', '', TRUE);?>
```